# Can someone tell me what is jsonMessage.errormessage means?

Tags: json

```
function showErrorMessage(formId,jsonMessage,targetId){
    clearErrorMessage(formId)   

    if(jsonMessage.errorMessage){
        $.each(jsonMessage.errorMessage,function(message){
            var errorMessageDOM = $('<span class="errorMessage"></span>');
            errorMessageDOM.message({type:"error", message:message,dismiss: false});
            $('#'+targetId).append(errorMessageDOM);
        })
    }else if(jsonMessage.fieldErrorMessage){
        $.each(jsonMessage.fieldErrorMessage,function(key,value){
            var errorMessageDOM = $('<span class="errorMessage"></span>');
            errorMessageDOM.message({type:"error", message:value,dismiss: false});

            var inputObj = $('#'+formId).find('input[name="'+key+'"],select[name="'+key+'"]');
            if(inputObj.length == 0){
                $('#'+targetId).append(errorMessageDOM);
            }
            inputObj.each(function(){
                if($(this).is("select")){
                    var parentSelector = $(this).parent('.selector');
                    if(parentSelector.length > 0){
                        errorMessageDOM.insertAfter(parentSelector);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                errorMessageDOM.appendTo($(this).parent());
            });
        })
    }
}
```

What is meant by the line jsonMessage.errorMessage in this function? I am stuck to understand this?

Answer (score 0):

it means this jsonMessage contains error message called errorMessage which is not null....

```
{"errorMessage":"something to put in your HTML"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a container for errors, with a generic name. Without seeing more of the code, we can only guess (unless someone recognises that particular code - Google and DuckDuckGo don't turn anything up for me).

It might be a part of the [jsonmessage](https://code.google.com/p/jsonmessage/) library, a JavaScript/JSON/AJAX messaging framework.

This contains references to an errorMessage property for errors like [exceptions while receiving errors from the server](https://code.google.com/p/jsonmessage/source/browse/trunk/lib/JSONMessage/JSONMessage.inc.js#1039).

Your function appears to be jQuery code to show either form field validation errors, or unspecified other errors. This might fit in the kind of errors that aren't field validation related.